# How to fix a Core Dumped error when it's after the function correctly executes?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, stl, coredump

I wrote C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class TreeNode {
public:
    T data;
    TreeNode<T> *left, *right;

    TreeNode() {
        data = {};
        left = right = NULL;
    }

    TreeNode(T data) {
        this->data = data;
    }
};

template <class T>
class BinaryTree {
public:
    TreeNode<T> *root;

    vector<T> _largestIndependentSet(TreeNode<T> *root) {
        static unordered_map< TreeNode<T>*, vector<T> > table;

        if(!root)
            return {};

        if(table.find(root) != table.end()) 
            return table[root];

        vector<T> lis = {}, lis_left = {}, lis_right = {},
            lis_nrl_left = {}, lis_nrl_right = {}, lis_nrr_left = {}, lis_nrr_right = {};

        // Leaf
        if(!root->left && !root->right) {
            lis.push_back(root->data);
        }else{
            if(root->left){
                lis_left = _largestIndependentSet(root->left);
                lis_nrl_left = _largestIndependentSet(root->left->left);
                lis_nrl_right = _largestIndependentSet(root->left->right);
            }

            if(root->right){
                lis_right = _largestIndependentSet(root->right);
                lis_nrr_left = _largestIndependentSet(root->right->left);
                lis_nrr_right = _largestIndependentSet(root->right->right);
            }
            if(     lis_left.size() + lis_right.size() > 
                    lis_nrl_left.size() + lis_nrl_right.size() +
                    lis_nrr_left.size() + lis_nrr_right.size() + 1      ){ // don't keep root
                lis.insert(lis.end(), lis_left.begin(), lis_left.end());
                lis.insert(lis.end(), lis_right.begin(), lis_right.end());
            }
            else {
                lis.insert(lis.end(), lis_nrl_left.begin(), lis_nrl_left.end());
                lis.insert(lis.end(), lis_nrl_right.begin(), lis_nrl_right.end());
                lis.insert(lis.end(), lis_nrr_left.begin(), lis_nrr_left.end());
                lis.insert(lis.end(), lis_nrr_right.begin(), lis_nrr_right.end());
                lis.push_back(root->data);
            }
        }
        cout<<"Calculated Results for: "<<root->data<<": ";
        for_each(lis.begin(), lis.end(), [](T data) {
            cout<<data<<" ";
        });
        cout<<"\n";
        table[root] = lis;
        return table[root];
    }

    void largestIndependentSet() {
        vector<T> lis = _largestIndependentSet(this->root);
        for_each(lis.begin(), lis.end(), [](T data) {
            cout<<data<<" ";
        });
    }
};

int main() {

    BinaryTree<int> bt;
    TreeNode<int> *root = new TreeNode<int>(10);
    root->left =  new TreeNode<int>(7);
    root->right =  new TreeNode<int>(15);
    root->left->left =  new TreeNode<int>(9);
    root->left->right =  new TreeNode<int>(12);
    root->right->left =  new TreeNode<int>(6);
    root->right->right =  new TreeNode<int>(11);
    root->left->left->left = new TreeNode<int>(20);
    root->right->left->right = new TreeNode<int>(5);
    root->left->left->left->left = new TreeNode<int>(22);
    root->left->left->left->right = new TreeNode<int>(21);
    root->right->left->right->left = new TreeNode<int>(4);
    root->right->left->right->right = new TreeNode<int>(3);
    bt.root = root;

    bt.largestIndependentSet();
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it using `g++ 5.4.0` on `Cygwin`:

```
g++ binary_tree.cpp -std=c++11
```

The problem is that the after the recursive function `_largestIndependentSet()` completes, the last print gives me the correct answer. But after that I get this error: **Aborted (core dumped)**, and the print in `largestIndependentSet()` doesn't execute.

This is baffling because my logic seems to be correct. What is causing this?

PS: If I compile it with `c++14` flag it runs fine o_O:

```
g++ binary_tree.cpp -std=c++14
```

Comment: You need to show how the pointers are created that are added to the map.  `vector<T> v = foo(some_apple);` is not enough information.  If you are storing pointers to local/temporary objects then those pointers are going to become invalid at some point.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: @NathanOliver The pointers already exist (it's a custom Binary Tree). The map is for storing additional information along with the vector. I'm certain that the vectors are not going out of scope.

Comment: Not the vectors but the `Apple<T>*`.  Storing raw pointers open you up to a whole host of problems.  We need to see how you get those pointers you are storing in the map.  A [mcve] would really help.

Comment: @NathanOliver I added a link to my actual code to the question.

Comment: The very first thing I would do is fix your `TreeNode` value constructor `TreeNode(T data)` to 1. use a member initialization list, and 2. Not leave the child left and right pointers *indeterminate*; a clear bug. I'd also fix `largestIndependentSet`, which doesn't actually *return* anything, but claims it does. Finally, that source list is borderline size, but imho would be ok to post as your repro case, so posting an unrelated "its like this" seems unnecessary.

Comment: It would be very useful to learn how to use a debugger. Also remember to never run gcc without `-Wall` (add more `-W`s to taste,  `-Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror` is a good set).

Comment: @WhozCraig It's a code just for  testing. My doubt was why am I getting a Core dumped error **after** the last line of _largestIndependentSet() has executed?

Comment: @n.m. Thanks! I was wondering about warnings myself but didn't look it up!

Comment: Put code *in* the question. Don't link to it.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 as I said, your value-constructor leaves the child `left` and `right` pointers dangling in the *indeterminate* wind. Your test `main` uses that constructor extensively, and your enumeration function establishes decision points based on those indeterminate values (null vs not). That alone means your code invokes *undefined behavior*. There is no sense in pursuing anything else until that is resolved. If there is a simpler way to say that, I'm pressed to find it. Fixing that, and the return value for `largestIndependentSet()`, and your code executes without coring on my mac.

Comment: @WhozCraig  AFAIK only dereferencing a NULL pointer is unpredictable. I'm **sure** I'm not doing that anywhere. And like I said, the code as expected. Only when the (first/parent) recursive call goes out of scope does it throw error. Also, I just tried it with C++14 and it works! Now Im more confused.

Comment: "...and the print in bar() doesn't execute..." Where's `bar()`?

Comment: When you get a crash at the end of the function, it is usually destructors. When it's at the end of the program (main) it can be global destructors. What you need to do is run the program in a debugger, like GDB, or through your IDE, and *see* where it crashes.

Comment: the memory leaks... my eyes... it burns... You know this isn't Java, right? Using `new` should be avoided wherever possible in user code - and it's usually possible because C++ provides many better ways, unlike other languages where `new` is unavoidable. Anyway, there's no garbage collector to save you if you `new` things without `delete`ing them later. Dunno if that's your problem here, but it will almost certainly create problems for you - or your users - later.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 "only dereferencing a NULL pointer is unpredictable." - that *not* true. Dereferencing a dangling pointer also invokes UB, as does dereferencing an *indeterminate* pointer. But moreover: *evaluating* indeterminate data, conditionally or otherwise, invokes undefined behavior. Period. Putting it simply, you have code that essentially does `if (ptr != NULL)`. If `ptr` wasn't granted a determinate value, that conditional eval invokes *undefined behavior*. It would be like `int x; if (x == 5) {...}`. Stop "trying" stuff and *fix the code*, including the missing retval mentioned.

Comment: @WhozCraig K I got it. Forgot to put that statement in second constructor! Lol you could have just pointed it out.

Comment: I did point it out. *twice*. And, did you fix the return missing return value for `largestIndependentSet()` ? that ultimately is, imo, the root of a lot of this.

Comment: vector<T> changing that to void fixed it. Can you add it as an answer so I can accept it. Also, can you please explain why that is NOT a compile error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not going into more than two major problems in the posted code.

- Indeterminate child pointer values for the `T`-value constructor.
- Missing return value for `largestIndependentSet()`

The former of these is common, especially for beginners in C++. Make sure you leave *nothing* with indeterminate value. In this case `left` and `right` in the `TreeNode(T value)` constructor were left indeterminate.

The latter of these, is hugely important. The function `largestIndependentSet()` claims it was returning a vector, but in reality had no `return` at all. That, likewise, invokes *undefined behavior*. From there I can speculate, but note that's all it is: speculation:

Speculation: The compiler happily generated the code that ultimately treated whatever happened to be residing on the activation stack, unset by you, as a `std::vector<T>`. Of course it is indeterminate gibberish because you never returned an actual object. But the invoke of the non-virtual destructor of `std::vector<>` certainly doesn't know that, and in so doing, treated whatever happened to be occupying what it thinks are its member variables as valid data, when in reality it was anything but. The short of it is this: take random memory, point `std::vector<>` destructor code at it, lie to the code and say that memory holds a valid `std::vector<>` object, then turn the destructor loose.

As to why the compiler didn't *error*. Well, often in C or C++, it simply isn't an error to do something unwise. The compiler expects you to know enough about what you're doing, and in this case, no language violations were present, so it gave you the benefit of the doubt. However... Turning up your compiler warning levels to pedantic heights will, on most modern compilers (icc, gcc, clang, and msvc for certain) *warn* you about your missing return value. Those warnings are there for a reason, and I strongly support turning them up *and* treating them as errors (also a compiler option).

Comment: I actually had initialized all pointers to NULL, but then I added a second constructor and forgot to copy that line. Been doing C++ long enough to know this!

Comment: @prakharsingh95 use member list initialization. It's a good habit, and in the case of complex objects, usually preferred, as it avoids unnecessary default initialization, `TreeNode(T const& value) : data(value), left(), right() {}`